# How do I send Push Notifications using Rails gems RPush or Houston?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, apple-push-notifications

I seem to be having trouble with both [RPush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#apple-push-notification-service) and [Houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston#usage).

Here's more or less what my controller looks like...

```
def create
    if authenticate_user
        post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
        if post
            comment = post.comments.new(comment_params.merge(user_id: params[:user_id]))

            Comment.transaction do
                if (comment.save)
                    apns_file = File.join(Rails.root, "APNSCert.pem")
                    app = Rpush::Apns::App.new
                    app.name = "My App"
                    app.certificate = File.read(apns_file)
                    app.environment = "sandbox" # APNs environment.
                    app.password = ENV["apns_certificate_password"] #figaro
                    app.connections = 1
                    app.save!

                    #SEND Push notification to the user who made the original post
                    post_user = User.find(post.user_id)
                    comment_user = User.find(comment.user_id)

                    if post_user && comment_user
                        rememeber_tokens_for_user = RememberToken.where("user_id = ?", post_user.id)
                        if rememeber_tokens_for_user.size > 0
                            rememeber_tokens_for_user.each do |remember_token|
                                # Create a notification that alerts a message to the user, plays a sound, and sets the badge on the app

                                alert = comment_user.name + ": " + comment.comment_text
                                if alert.length > 50
                                    alert = alert[0..46] + "..."
                                end

                                n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
                                n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("My App")
                                n.device_token = remember_token.device_token
                                n.alert = alert
                                n.data = { foo: "bar" }
                                n.save!
```

It appears my server on heroku is getting an error on the `app.save!` line, `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name has already been taken):`.

I'm no more than an intermediate in rails, so any help would be appreciated. Am I suppose to put the 'app' variable section of code into a separate class that is somehow only called once or something, similar to a singleton in objective-c? It apparently doesn't like when it's accessed by a different user POSTing to this resource, which is when I get this error.

Should I take a stab at Grocer, since I can't seem to get Houston or RPush working?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `RPush` gem, but it seems that you cannot duplicate the `name` of the app. Is it possible that you only need to create an `Rpush::Apns::App` once, i.e. when `Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("My App")` returns `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not need to do the APN setup more than once per app. That's exactly why you're having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a check to create an app only when there is not one already created:

```
if !Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("My App")
    app.name = "My App"
    app.certificate = File.read(apns_file)
    app.environment = "sandbox" # APNs environment.
    app.password = ENV["apns_certificate_password"] #figaro
    app.connections = 1
    app.save!
end
```